# Vue Axios function including an async function result

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs2, axios

This is my vue.js function, it calls a python API . THe problem is around AWAIT

```
 async getLinearSolver() {
          
            const path = '/api/nutritional_constraints_1';
            
            var vm = this

            var json = await this.formatDataForPulp()
            
            axios.post(path,json )
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    vm.linear_result = "Write my res data "   
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
```

`console.log(res)` is ok :

```
Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
```

but no template modification is possible, can't assign any variable to  vm.linear_result

`vm.linear_result = "Write my res data "` is not working

:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"

found in

---> <NutritionalConstraints> at src/components/NutritionalConstraints.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
    webpackContextResolve .*$:51
    webpackContext .*$:45
    render NutritionalConstraints.vue:216
    renderList VueJS
    render NutritionalConstraints.vue:165
    VueJS 14
    _callee$/< NutritionalConstraints.vue:235
    promise callback*_callee$ NutritionalConstraints.vue:220
    Babel 11
    onSubmit NutritionalConstraints.vue:290
    VueJS 21
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
```

Please help me, I really don't know what to do .

I have a similar query with no external AWAIT function, it works perfectly .

THis is a simplier example that leads to the same problem:

```
 async getLinearSolver() {
          
            const path = '/api/nutritional_constraints_1';
            
            var vm = this
           
            this.formatDataForPulp().then((res) => {
                    console.log(res) // Working
                     vm.a_template_variable ="Write my res data "// Not working !  
                })

           
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found out the problem .

I needed to deep clone some json array inside of my formatDataForPulp() function .
Like this :

```
 var  data = {
                "items": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items)), // WE need to do a deep clone otherwize it crashes vue.js 
                "constraints": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.constraints)) // WE need to do a deep clone otherwize it crashes vue.js 
        }
```

I was not doing it before, so vue.js was modifying my 2 way binding data during my formatDataForPulp() function, and then, vue.js was crashing !! THe problem was not coming from the ASYNC system.

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` to deepClone has limitations and can lead to unexpected results. These are outlined [here](https://medium.com/@pmzubar/why-json-parse-json-stringify-is-a-bad-practice-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript-b28ac5e36521).